# jquery getjson not

Tags: jquery, json

I have this html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON('test.json', function (data) {
                var items = [];

                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
                });

                $('<ul/>', {
                    'class': 'my-new-list',
                    html: items.join('')
                }).appendTo('body');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this test.json file

```
{
  "one": "Singular sensation",
  "two": "Beady little eyes",
  "three": "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
}
```

I have validated the json file and it seems ok but the results are not being appended to the body tag. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check the console for errors, and did you log the data to see what you're recieving ?

Comment: Use firebug or something similar to make sure you are receiving the data and that your test.json file is being found.

Comment: Seems like it is a Chrome bug. The code works properly in Firefox and IE.

Comment: @mpora - There's no such thing as a Chrome bug!

Comment: Chrome doesn't let you run ajax off the file system, need to be on a server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it was working but because I had not tested it in other browsers other than Chrome, I could not see the results. Thanks to @Jack for mentioning that Chrome doesn't run ajax off the file system. The issue was discussed upon here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787 for those interested.